# Redirect any url which have specific keyword

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to redirect url to specific url which includes `/for-your-practice/`.
if we get to know that url contains `for-your-practice` just redirect it to the url i want. which would be `https://www.example.com/first/second/order/shop/product-category/for-your-practice/`
Tried solutions so far:
First:

```
Redirect /for-your-practice/ 
https://www.example.com/first/second/order/shop/product-category/for-your-practice/
```

Second:

```
Redirect 302 https://www.example.com/first/second/order/shop/for-your-practice/ https://www.example.com/first/second/order/shop/product-category/for-your-practice/
```

Third:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} www.example.com/first/second/order/shop/product-category/for-your-practice [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /for-your-practice [R,L]
```

Fourth:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /for-your-practice/
 RewriteRule .*$ http://www.example.com/first/second/order/shop/product-category/for-your-practice [L,R=301]
```

unfortunately none of them worked, what's wrong i'm doing here ?
`.htaccess`

Comment: It is unclear what you actually want to do, since your attempts contradict themselves. In what direction do you want to rewrite? What is an example URL request coming in and what should it get rewritten to?

Comment: @arkascha i want to redirect any link containing `/for-your-practice/` to specific link i want to. i modified my question please check if it makes sense now ?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest probably is to use apache's rewriting module:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /for-your-practice/
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/first/second/order/shop/product-category/for-your-practice/ [R=301]
```

For this some preconditions have to apply:

- the interpretation of `.htaccess` tyle files has to be enabled
- the rewriting module has to be loaded
- the `.htaccess` style file has to be located in your `DocumentRoot`
- the `.htaccess` style file has to be readable by the http server process

Reason for the use of an additional `RewriteCond` is that preceding slashes in URLs can raise issues with `RewriteRule`s in `.htaccess` style files. IN general you should *always* prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server, often without need. Those files are only provided as a last means for situations where one can *not* use the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers) or for applications that need to write their own rewriting rules (which obviously is a security nightmare).

Comment: **END** with an external redirection?

Comment: @starkeen True, does not make much sense. Thanks.

Comment: @HabibRehman And "not working" means what _exactly_? What happens? What do you see in your http servers error log file? Are the preconditions I named _really_ fulfilled?

Comment: @HabibRehman And once more: please give a _precise_ example of a request URL you test with. Not something vague as "link containing".

Comment: sorry for security purpose i can't share the site link, as even after sharing it wont work for any other person

Comment: @HabibRehman Sorry, but that is nonsense. 1. if it won't work, then what is the security risk? 2. if you publish content under a URL it is available in the internet. Your only protection is that you do not hand out the URL? 3. we are not interested in the domain name, but the path. Only that is what is relevant in this scenario. So one more: what is the request you test with?

Comment: the whole scenario i want to redirect it the url `https://www.example.com/first/second/order/shop/for-your-practice/` lacks `/product-category/` so i want to redirect `https://www.example.com/first/second/order/shop/product-category/for-your-practice/` here

Comment: What about the other questions I asked?

Comment: And are you _really_ certain that you want to test for the trailing slash in `/for-your-pra‌​ctice/`?

Comment: @HabibRehman And why do you want an external redirect which I assumed considering that you named a full URL as desired target. The previous explanation implies that this is only an internal redirect?

Comment: @arkascha not really but catching these words would be necessary as there would be other words to redirect pages too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127211/discussion-between-arkascha-and-habib-rehman).